# MySQL #1054 - Unknown column 'notes.schedule_id' in 'field list'

Tags: mysql

I have a query and I have all the tables name correctly. And suddenly, I get this error. I dont know what should I do. I even make an alias in the `sections` table because I got an previous error of `#1066 - Not unique table/alias: 'sections'`. Can someone tell me what should I do? Thanks

```
SELECT sectionschedules.id, notes.schedule_id, 
sections.id as b, sectionstudents.section_id, users.id, sections.sy_id FROM sections
LEFT JOIN sectionschedules on sectionschedules.id = notes.schedule_id
LEFT JOIN sections b on sections.id = sectionschedules.section_id
LEFT JOIN sectionstudents on sectionstudents.section_id = sections.id
LEFT JOIN users on users.id = sectionstudents.student_id
WHERE users.id = 10 AND sections.sy_id = 1 AND notes.status = 1;
```

Comment: You have no table or alias called `notes` in the query.

Comment: i have table `notes` sir.

Comment: Not in the query you have posted.

Comment: do you mean i dont have a `notes` table in joins sir?

Comment: Yes, that is what I mean.

Comment: how do I call it? should i replace `FROM sections` into notes?

Comment: can you show the image of your database ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have no table `notes` in your query that's why you cant execute correctly your query.

You call `notes.schedule_id,` and `notes.status = 1;`

Edited : :D

```
SELECT sections.name, sections.description, ss.id,
sections.id as b, ss.section_id, users.id, sections.sy_id FROM sections
    LEFT JOIN sectionschedules ss on sections.id = ss.section_id
    LEFT JOIN sectionstudents on sectionstudents.section_id = sections.id
    LEFT JOIN users on users.id = sectionstudents.student_id
    LEFT JOIN notes on ss.id = notes.schedule_id
```

check your where clause . 
and analyze it . 
Thanks .

Comment: so what should I do sir?

Comment: call a table `notes` . or use another `join` for that. :D

Comment: shoud I replace `FROM sections` into `FROM notes?`

Comment: i think . try it . because your table `sections` call in twice .

Comment: check in `Line : 2`  and `Line : 4`

Comment: now i get `1054 - Unknown column 'sections.id' in 'field list'` error sir.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200628/discussion-between-ronald-bustillo-and-jervz09).

Comment: I think you gave me an outdated data. that's why . your where clause is not match. hehe